# Save Document library lookup field using Rest API

Tags: 2013, document-library, lookup-column, custom-list, rest

How can I save document library lookup field using REST API Post in a SharePoint list?
I tried like

```
'docItem':'1;#test'
```

But, it is throwing an error :

> {"error":{"code":"-1,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A
>   'PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to
>   read the value of a navigation property; however, a 'StartArray' node,
>   a 'StartObject' node, or a 'PrimitiveValue' node with null value was
>   expected."}}} Bad Request

Answer (score 1):

`'docItem':'1'`, simple this should work.. Or you can try `'docItem':1`

Answer (score 1):

In REST, adding 'Id' to the column works as long as your specifying the Id.

LookupColumn: "docItem"

```
"docItemId" : 1
```